# Variables in Handlebars

Tags: variables, handlebars.js

I'm passing models to a handlebars template and putting a few of the properties in a row. I want to have some sort of position variable for each row. Specifically, I want to know how many rows have been created and have a position associated with each row.

e.g.

```
{{#each row}}
<span class = (indexHere)>
  <tr>
     <td> <{{this.property}}>
  </tr>
</span>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question and maybe at that time Handlebars did not include the `@index` property, but according to current (1.3.0) documentation:

When looping through items in `each`, you can optionally reference the current loop index via `{{@index}}`

Answer (score 3):

You make your own helper :-)

Here's one you can steal:
https://gist.github.com/1048968

Comment: in the coffee solution given there, it has the line item.index = _i , does item.index create a new property on the item object?

Comment: Yes I believe so (but my Coffeescript is rusty so I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: sorry, one more question, lets say I've written a helper that keeps track of position, lets say I now want to use that same variable in another tag (e.g. I want class for a span to be index AND class for a td to be index) how do i achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, but I think that qualifies as a new SO post :-)  More importantly, the answer depends on the details (like do you have two entirely separate templates or one template with both or ...), so asking a new question, that includes your actual code, is really the best way to proceed.